# What are the mentorship awards available in acoustics / bioacoustics / ocean acoustics?

Tags: education, graduate-school

My PhD supervisor was a phenomenal mentor and I would really like him to be recognized for it. I nominated him for the [David T Blackstock Mentorship Award](https://asastudents.org/mentor-award/) from the Acoustical Society of America but this hasn't been successful (yet). Although, I will keep nominating him for that award, I am looking for other mentorship awards out there.

Any suggestions for other mentorship awards available in the fields of acoustics, bioacoustics, or ocean acoustics ?

Answer (score 5):

The idea of a mentorship award is fantastic, and research suggests that recognition is more important than monetary value of an award (see [here](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/mind-the-manager/201306/new-employee-study-shows-recognition-matters-more-money)).  Could this be a 'if you build it, they will come' situation?

Perhaps the [Bioacoustics Technical Committee](https://tcabasa.org/) (Acoustical Society of America) would consider having their own Mentorship award to encourage both strong mentorship and recognition of strong mentorship in our community. Given the growth of bioacoustics (with no slowing down!), ASA Bioacoustics might find this a worthwhile consideration.

Answer (score 3):

- Hmm, good question. I have heard about the [Nature Award for Mentoring in Science](https://www.nature.com/nature/awards/mentorship). This seems really appropriate, but they highlight a given country each year and only take on nominations from that country.
- The [Oceanography Society also has a mentorship award](https://tos.org/mentoring-award-nominations), which could maybe be relevant to your previous supervisor (?)
- Also - I once tried to nominate a collaborator for a [Marsh Award for Ecology](https://www.britishecologicalsociety.org/membership-community/honours-awards-and-prizes/marsh-award-for-ecology/), awarded anually by the British Ecological Society (nominees can be from whereever). While it's not one specifically for mentorship, it's one that recognizes their contributions to the field (which I think would encompass mentorship).